# How to set Safari print margins via CSS to print borderless

Tags: css, printing, webkit

I want to print a webpage to PDF without any margins in Safari. Page size is set to 'A4 borderless' in the print dialogue.

Whatever I seem to do, Safari on OSX is adding an extra margin around my HTML. Check 'print backgrounds' to see what I mean.

Clearly the @page-rule has no effect for Safari, but are there any other ways?

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/psFHC/

```
@page {
  size: 21cm 29.7cm;   /*A4*/
  margin: 0; /*webkit says no*/
}

html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 100%; 
    background: #eee;
}
```

​

Comment: You have a `padding: 5%` further down in your code, is that already calculated in?

Comment: Yes, setting it to 0 makes no difference, I removed it from the question to make it clearer.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=%40page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is 3 things to take in consideration:

1. The margin of the page's rule, unfortunately

   ```
   @page {
   margin: 0cm !important;
   }
   ```

   Has no effect on Safari 6, where it does in Chrome 23. As I know, as long as Safari is not supporting this, there is no solution (it seems to be fixed to around 10mm).
2. The page setting as seen [here](http://support.gliffy.com/entries/246980-print-on-the-mac-osx-with-no-margins) you might have to define a custom "Paper Size" in the "Print…" menu panel without any margin (you did it already btw).
3. Obviously to take care of the other inner content html, body… not to have any margin.

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly point 1 that was puzzling me. So for now I just have to wait for a fix in Safari, or use Chrome instead.

Comment: As of late 2016 we are still waiting for Safari to obey the @page element. This is very frustrating because it makes it very difficult to use Safari to print things like labels defined in HTML/CSS.

Comment: I defined a custom paper size without any margin but the preview showed that safari was still clearly shrinking my SVG to the same margin. $!@#!@

Comment: @EFC :) now its 2019 and still true, and sadly for the other Browsers. It just seems more important to generate evermore bloated Javascript APIs, incresing thereby potential to remote code exploits and tons privacy issues, than to implement a  HTML/CSS way some reasonable way to be able to print out something. 2019, still no printing.

Answer (score 4):

The selected answer isn't quite right. To correctly answer the question you need to understand the problem first.

**Borderless printing and printers:**

Very few printers can "actually" print borderless prints even if they say they do. Most just enlarge the print a bit so it stretches beyond the actual page and, usually, give you a slider to adjust that amount. The reason is that most printer don't have a sensor to determine where the paper actually is, it presumes paper is there and for most prints it doesn't matter if it's 0,5mm off or even 1mm.

For borderless it matters because the print comes out with a white (paper) border around it.

For this reason 95% of printers out there mimic this "borderless" print by actually running ink into thin air for a little bit just so the paper is covered all the way to the edge. Printing into thin air is bad, can cause smudges in the long term and should be avoided, so the amount of printing over the edge must be adjusted to a minimum.

Good large format printers have a sensor to detect paper width but it's used to adjust the paper slightly because the length, 50 to 150m per roll, can cause even a 0,1mm misalignment to become a problem and cause paper jams.

To fix this problem entirely, "bleed" is used, where you actually design everything to a slightly larger paper which is cut to size afterwards.

*Ok... now you know.*

**Onwards to the problem of CSS borderless prints:**

To fully understand this problem one must be acquainted with the "Box".

[image: Box Model]

The Box models the behaviour of almost every element in CSS. The page you want to print is usually wrapped in a tag of some sort, either a div with and id or a class like this:

```
<div class="page">lots of content</div>
```

We will be talking about the black line, called the *border*, and it's two siblings "margin" and "padding".

Unbeknownst to most is the fact that every printer out there actually reports the margins within it can print for every paper size it supports.

Here is an HP 2800dtn doing so (just hover over the paper size for a while and it will appear).

[image: HP 2800dtn]

**The "fix":**

Safari is doing the right thing. There I said it... it's not a bug.

The reason it apparently refuses to produce borderless prints is that it's actually not possible (in the real world). You can do it, but people printing it at 100% zoom will have the content trimmed off by the printer, which, as I've described, can't print to the edge.

So most will have to "fit to paper" margins (the default OS X behaviour, minified to around 98% zoom) then enable borderless mode on the printer which in turn magnifies the minified 98% zoom version to 103%. If you do the math you get a weird number of probably 101.5% of the original version (I can't say for sure, I'm not very good at math if it isn't divided by two :) 
This isn't exactly a problem for fonts and vector graphics, but it wreaks havoc in the pixel world. The pixel world likes, just like I do, the number 2 by default, the rest is just "smoothing" it over.

*So you can't fix it, because it isn't broken. Safari puts the border of the div and all its inner elements inside the "printable area" of the paper as reported by the printer. Good!*

**The solution:**

You can't know the printer margins until you command+p *and* select a paper size.

But what can you do in CSS to get that "what you see is what you get" feeling everyone likes?

1. Use the margin on the div.page you defined. Note that margin is calculated form the the element containing that div. So you need to wrap the `page` in the `actualpage`

Define CSS per media type so that the screen shows imaginary print margins (close to the real thing) and the print get's a version without margins.

```
/* @media all { */ /* I like using these */
  div.actualpage {
   ...
   height: 210mm; /* DIN A4 standard paper size */
   width: 297mm;
   ...
  }
  div.page {
   ...
   /* margin: 0;  you don't really have to explicitly set it to 0 unless it's already set to something else */
   ...
  }
/* } */

@media screen {
 div.page {
  ...
  margin: 5mm 5mm 5mm 10mm; /* printers usually have a bigger bottom margin*/
  ...
  }
}

@media print {
 div.page {
  ...
  margin: 0mm; /* Browser will apply the correct margins when it prints */
  ...
  }
}
```

If you can't wrap the page into another div you can hack it (ie: less elegant solution) with padding.

```
/* @media all { */ /* I like using these */
  div.page {
   ...
   height: 210mm; /* DIN A4 standard paper size */
   width: 297mm;
   /* padding: 0;  you don't really have to explicitly set it to 0 unless it's already set to something else */
   ...
  }
/* } */

@media screen {
 div.page {
  ...
  padding: 5mm 5mm 5mm 10mm; /* printers usually have a bigger bottom margin*/
  ...
  }
}

@media print {
 div.page {
  ...
  padding: 0mm; /* Browser will apply the correct margins when it prints */
  ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand the principles of bleeding and paper borders. Yet I defined a custom paper size reporting 0 mm margin in the print dialog that doesn't work as expected in Safari 9. It does work in Chrome 46, even when you use the system dialog.

Comment: This is quite simply incorrect. Safari is ***not*** doing the right thing by completely ignoring the CSS `@page` declaration (and that is not related to what the margin is set to). It simply ignores `@page` completely. Everything in the accepted answer is absolutely correct. It is of course true that you can’t know accurate page margins on a given printer until you’ve selected both the printer and the page size—but this question is about _printing to PDF_, unhampered by the physical limitations of having to handle paper and spray ink on it. A PDF printer can print borderless with no problems.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "A ... printer can print borderless with no problems." not *all* printers...

Comment: @unmircea Can you point me to a _PDF_ printer (that is, not a physical printer, but a piece of software that creates a PDF file from some kind of input) that cannot create a PDF file without borders? If there is one, I've never seen it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You're right, however one has to point out that these files won't be printable "as-is" in all printers. I usually get upset at Preview on macOS, it always "fits to page" making the scale a dubious 103%, 106% or 97.4% to account for this. I constantly have to go back change it to 100% and then check to see if any content exceeds the printable area.

Comment: This answer misses the point. Even on printers that report their margins, there are use cases where I really want to force Safari to ignore that and print to the margins I specify, even if that means cutting off output. The case I've run into a few times is when I write CSS to print labels on label paper. I need very precise control to do this properly, controls Chrome allows and Safari ignores.

Comment: @EFC For thermal printers it is best to generate an image of the entire webpage and print that. Thermal printers usually print the entire width and have no concept of borders. What printers do you use?

Comment: @unmircea, I am talking about cases where page geometry is more important that getting everything printed on the page. I am using a laser printer that does enforce a margin, but that is not relevant. I need CSS and HTML that guarantees elements fall at a particular spot on the actual page. If that spot is in the printer margin, then I accept they may not actually print. The use case stated above is mailing labels. In that case, I need each element to center properly on each label. On some printers, this may mean the label edges do not print fully, but they print in the right spot on the page.

Comment: @unmircea, also note that I may not actually "print" the page. Often I just want to produce a PDF, for printing elsewhere. In this case I also want to ignore the printer margin since that margin is irrelevant to the final printing anyway. Safari will not let me do that. Chrome does allow me to remove margins altogether when printing to PDF (or, for that matter, when printing to a printer).

Comment: @unmicrea in my experience safari just refuses to scale properly whereas in Chrome I can easily verify proper scaling by printing an 8.5 in wide SVG that extends to the edges of a marginless Letter size page.  Safari is just being an ass.

Comment: @unmircea also, even Adobe Acrobat allows you to print an 8.5 x 11 document to the edges of Letter paper if you select the no scaling option.  And if anyone knows what users need, it's Adobe.  Requiring some margin is the right thing when the user's goal is to print everything they see -- but when the user's goal is to print something to exact scale (a map, for instance) it is totally wrong for their needs.

Comment: @unmircea and as far as I can tell (from printing out protractors) when the scale in the Safari print dialog is 100%, it's not actually true size -- it's *100% of its pre-scaled-down size* from the unavoidable margins.

Comment: @Andy That is what I said, it treats 100% as being the printable area of the paper as reported by the printer. It is the right way to do it, I know it doesn't seem that way. It's the printer's job to deal with margins not the software's. Printers

Comment: @EFC Please keep in mind it's not the software's job to print but the printers. If the printer doesn't report margin of zero, then why try to print there with software. In architectural drawings where scale is important another method is used, no matter what margins the printer reports the cad package positions the center of the drawing to the center of the page and lets the margins flow out. People get huge problems with this when they print on one A3 laser printer and it's fine and another misses a titleblock line. It even happens on the same printer if the paper slips a bit.

Comment: @EFC "I need CSS and HTML that guarantees elements fall at a particular spot on the actual page." This approach to printing is similar to what the old dot matrix printers did, and still do today. Because the "dot" was so big it's resolution could be used as a kind of coordinate system and you could "draw" dots at exactly the position you wanted. These printers still do that today and are used for printing multiple copies of invoices at the same time. They are horrible to program for.

Comment: Software really has no idea what it's printing to. The days when the software was aware of the exact hardware implementation of a printer and has access to somekind of low level coordinate system are long gone. It's sad, believe me, I know. What's even worse is Bootstrap's @media print { display:none; } and an internet future where nobody cares about printing. We'll be screenshoting pages for print to fix it...

Comment: @unmircea apparently you know better than Adobe about this...I'm downvoting your answer.

Comment: @unmircea you tell me which app you would prefer to use to print out something that needs to be exact scale: Safari, where you have to reverse-engineer its hardcoded margins and calculate what to zoom it to above "100%", or Acrobat, where you just tell it to print without any auto-scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Thermal label printers can print without margins. This is but one use case. I am sure there are more.
I have just added

```
@page {margin:0 !important}
```

to my stylesheet and Safari took it. So, it must be fixed.