# @page css rule alternative for safari

Tags: html, css, printing, safari, media-queries

How can I use write alternatives for these rules in safari? 
I am using `angularPrint` directive for adding print functionality to some of my pages, which adds some helper [classes](https://github.com/samwiseduzer/angularPrint/blob/master/angularPrint.css) to my document and also use `@page` directive, everything works fine in all browsers except [safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40page), I found that these rules are not supported by safari, So I am looking for alternatives for these rules. Any suggestion?

```
 @page {
    margin: 0cm;
    /*size: A4 landscape;*/
  }

  @page :first {
    margin-top: 0cm;
  }

  @page :left {
    margin-left: 0cm;
    margin-right: 0cm;
  }

  @page :right {
    margin-left: 0cm;
    margin-right: 0cm;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide sample link to check.

Comment: @Sharvan https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40page says that safari is not supported.

Comment: tried with @media print?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154147/how-to-set-safari-print-margins-via-css-to-print-borderless

I've hit this Safari limitation repeatedly. As of 2019, it still seems the only way to get consistent printing across browsers is to do it on the server. :(

Comment: I remember we handled such scenario with writing a complete css from scratch and dynamically opening a new html file via JavaScript..

Answer (score -5):

Try using below.

```
@page {
    margin: 2in;    /* default for all pages */
}
@page :left {
    margin: 1in;    /* margin on left page */
}
@page :right {
    margin: 3in;    /* margin on right page */
}
@page :first {
    margin-top: 5in;    /* top margin on first page */
}
```

as per the link https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-reference/css-page-rule.php

Comment: The other person is asking it specifically for Safari browser and page rules are not supported by Safari. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page